# Flex puts _docs_ folder into the bin. Can that be stopped?

Tags: flash, ide, flex-builder-3

I started using Flex Builder 3 only recently. There is a behavior I want to change. Flex apparently looks for folders that have underscore in front of their names inside the libraries on the project path, and transfers them to the bin directory. This often results in several megabytes of junk in my bin, and I want to change this behavior.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the folders to ***not*** have an underscore in front of their name?

Comment: Odd, why is the "not" showing in **bold** but not *italics* and it shows two asterisks instead?!?